# Получить список системных библиотек swift'а на MacOS для разных систем в CMake3.28

Tags: c++, ios, swift, macos, cmake

**Предисловие:**

Проект на C++ линкуется к динамической библиотеке, которая использует Swift, но CMake этого не видит и не подкладывает нужные либы.

В связи с этим появляется множество ошибок вида

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'libswiftCompatibility*' not found
*link errors*
```

**Что сделал:**

**Первый вариант** решения проблемы - добавить в исходники пустой файлик .swift, что стриггерит  xcodebuild и сам подложит либы

**Второй вариант** я взял из [репозитория Apple](https://github.com/apple/swift-cmake-examples/blob/main/3_bidirectional_cxx_interop/cmake/modules/InitializeSwift.cmake), но он работает только для MacOS.
Мне нужна такая же функциональность для iOS.

Что бы получить список либ и для MacOS, и для iOS, достаточно вызвать команду

```
swiftc -sdk /path/to/sdk/<platform>.sdk -target <triple> -print-target-info
```

где `<triple>` - строка формата arm64-apple-macos17.2 и для разных платформ, она, очевидно, разная

В CMake я написал такую реализацию

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE SDK_PATH
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
execute_process(
    COMMAND xcrun --show-sdk-platform-version --sdk
            ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE SDK_VERSION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
    set(TARGET_PLATFORM "macos")
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "iOS")
    set(TARGET_PLATFORM "ios")
endif()
set(SDK_FLAGS
    "-sdk"
    "${SDK_PATH}"
    "-target"
    "${CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES}-apple-${TARGET_PLATFORM}${SDK_VERSION}"
)
```

**И вопрос вот в чем:**

Есть ли какой-то более красивый/корректный способ получить список либ (в данном случае меня напрягает способ получения `<triple>`, мне кажется в один момент что-нибудь да отвалится)
или возможно в новом CMake есть способ прилинковать все либы без каких либо издевательств